# Android Webview memory increases

Tags: android, memory, webview, memory-leaks

I am using android webview in my app for browsing. All the pages load fine. no issues. But as I keep browsing (opening links) the memory keeps increasing. For example: 3 pages navigated its 60 mb and after it reaches a point the app crashes.

Now, these are regular websites like cnn.com, gmail.com, gap.com etc

Any ideas or pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar issue. I have several webviews in several activities that loads all kind of pages even internal html. I free and destroy the webviews and even the activities in every change of activities and it doesnt matter.....some online contents loading, usually, make all the webviews start to get affected incrementally in performance....when i go in offline html saved usually goes fine. I dont understand how can affect, is there a global setting or something that affects all??

Answer (score 0):

You should use caching to avoid such memory leaks!
loaded images can be cached on disk and loaded incrementally.
Here is a [generic caching library](https://github.com/wareninja/generic-store-for-android) together with [example usage >>](https://github.com/wareninja/generic-store-for-android/tree/master/demo-example/src/com/wareninja/opensource/genericstore_example)

Comment: The page doesn't necessarily have images.... just google.com homepage takes 25 mb...